# Evaluating a numerical integral at a point

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

Can we evaluate a numerical integration at a point? Consider the following example:

```
g = NIntegrate[(1 - 2/Sqrt[4 + r^2])/Sqrt[1 + (4 + r^2)^2 (1 - 2/Sqrt[4 + r^2])^2],{r,0,u}];
```

Since I know that *Mathematica* can not solve this integral analytically, I ask it to solve this integral numerically (for example, I solve this integral for $1/2<r< 5/2$). Now I need a list of data that contains the value of `g` for each different values of `u`. How can I get this list?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "numerical integration in a point."  You have an integral of the form $$\int_1^2 f(r) \, dr.$$  If this is your input for a general $f(r)$, what do you want your output to be?

Comment: Do you mean `NDSolve[{f'[r] == (1 - 2/Sqrt[4 + r^2])/Sqrt[1 + (4 + r^2)^2 (1 - 2/Sqrt[4 + r^2])^2], f[1] == 0}, f, {r, 1, 2}]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 that is a nice way to look at it!

Comment: Re  Michael Seifert and MichaelE2 : Thank you very much for your help. I have corrected my question.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
v = 
  Table[
    {u,
     NIntegrate[
       (1 - 2/Sqrt[4 + r^2])/Sqrt[1 + (4 + r^2)^2 (1 - 2/Sqrt[4 + r^2])^2], 
       {r, 1, u}]},
    {u, 1, 2, .05}];
Column[v]
```

[image: table]

Comment: Re m_goldberg: Yes, That's it, Thank you very much

Comment: @Somayeh.H. I am glad my answer helped you. You can make your thanks more valuable to me by accepting this answer. Just click on the check mark you see under the voting score on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessesing they want something like this

```
f[to_] := 
 NIntegrate[(1 - 2/Sqrt[4 + r^2])/
   Sqrt[1 + (4 + r^2)^2 (1 - 2/Sqrt[4 + r^2])^2], {r, 1, to}, Method -> "TrapezoidalRule"]

data = Table[{r, f[r]}, {r, 1, 2, .1}];

ListStepPlot[data, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"Integral vale", None}, {"r", 
    "Showing integral as r increases"}}, BaseStyle -> 14, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]